# RabbitMQ subscriber timeout

Tags: java, messaging, rabbitmq, firewall, cisco

I have an issue when subscribing to RabbitMQ messages when traversing a CISCO ASA 5505 firewall. It appears there is some kind of timeout in the firewall which closes idle connections and results in my RabbitMQ subscription silently being dropped. The result is my subscriber doesn't throw/display any exception but doesn't receive published messages.

```
public class RabbitMqSubscriber<T extends Serializable> implements Subscriber<T> {

    private QueueingConsumer consumer;
    private MessageListener<T> listener;
    private String exchange;
    private String topic;
    public RabbitMqSubscriber(String host,String exchange,String topic) throws IOException {
        this.exchange=exchange;
        this.topic=topic;
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
            factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(10);
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, "topic");
        String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        channel.queueBind(queueName, exchange, topic);
        consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery;
            try {
                delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
                Object o=SerializationUtils.deserialize(delivery.getBody());
                listener.receive((T)o);
            } catch (ShutdownSignalException | ConsumerCancelledException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setListener(MessageListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener=listener;
    }

}
```

I've also tried adding keepalive to the server config but this hasn't helped either:

```
[        {rabbit, [{tcp_listen_options, [binary, 
                     {packet, raw}, 
                     {reuseaddr, true}, 
                     {backlog, 128}, 
                     {nodelay, true}, 
                     {exit_on_close, false}, 
                     {keepalive, true}]}]}].
```

Comment: This appears to be a firewall issue...works fine on intranet but not when passing through firewall.

Comment: You could implement your own heartbeat messages to keep connections alive - you could have your subscriber send messages to the queue and receive them back again.

Answer (score 0):

try setting a connection timeout with your connection factory:

```
factory.setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: the firewall has a cache for network address translation (NAT) entries with a limited storage capacity and therefore drops idle connections. The timeout can be increased  if memory resources are still sufficent. [This CISCO documentation](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-5527) says the normal timeout is 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears there is some kind of timeout in the firewall which closes idle connections and results in my RabbitMQ subscription silently being dropped.

Correct.  Cisco ASA will time-out inactive TCP sockets under the following circumstances:

1. The tcp socket exceeds the ASA's idle-timeout value
2. The tcp socket exceeds a NAT xlate idle timeout

I am more familiar with Cisco ASA than RabbitMQ.  From what I can see, it looks like you are somehow not getting TCP keepalives on this session even though you tried configuring it.

Please try different methods of enabling tcp keepalives. Either call `setRequestedHeartbeat` on the `ConnectionFactory` before creating a new connection, or, subclass `ConnectionFactory`, override the `configureSocket` method, and call `socket.setKeepAlive(true)`.

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions. I had the same problem when connecting to a cloud server in rackspace where I have no control over the firewall and keepalives have no effect.